# Relative click location in a DataGridView Cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have been looking a solution for my problem.
I'm trying to detect a click, when this click is performed in the last `20px` of my Cell, relative position (starting from left).

I have reviewed some similar situations without success because they detect the left upper corner `x, y` point of the clicked cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could intercept the Mouse click position in the [CellMouseDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmousedown?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CellMouseDown);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) event. This will give you the relative position of the pointer inside the current cell:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.X > (sender as DataGridView)[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Size.Width - 20)
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked right there!");
}
```